# Should you secure a Pending Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I understand that a PendingIntent is a token that you give to another application (e.g. Notification Manager, Alarm Manager or other 3rd party applications), which allows this other application to use the permissions of your application to execute a predefined piece of code. Does it make sense to secure a pending intent through a custom permission? In my app I am returning a Pending Intent within an Intent to another app through an AIDL call...getBuyIntent. I am not sure if I should secure the pending intent through a custom Android permission.

Comment: "which allows this other application to use the permissions of your application to execute a predefined piece of code" -- more accurately, it allows the other application to start an activity, start a service, or send a broadcast, using the rules as if your app was the one doing those things. "Does it make sense to secure a pending intent" -- you cannot secure the `PendingIntent`. You can secure the component that will be started by the `PendingIntent`.